# Having extracted the blood vessels, how to brighten them?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy

I've used Kirsch filter to try and obtain the blood vessels, but the result isn't the best, as shown below:

[image]

Although the vessels have been obtained, they aren't bright enough. How do I go about making them 'more visible'?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a solution to your specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on retina vessel detection for a bit few years ago, and there are different ways to do it:

- If you don't need a top result but something fast, you can use oriented openings, [see here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3327391_Segmentation_of_vessel-like_patterns_using_mathematical_morphology_and_curvature_evaluation) and [here](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/Anciens/zana/).
- Then you have an other version using mathematical morphology [version here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiJ1qDb-cXMAhUMOsAKHaXXBcoQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcmm.ensmp.fr%2F~walter%2Farticles_walter%2Fwalterklein.pdf.gz&usg=AFQjCNG3e1Ueke67eY9JEw6ub00Y8roQ-A&sig2=dzVYD_5_2BKMaOQpRLjjOQ&cad=rja).

For better results, here are some ideas:

- Personally, I used combination of Gabor filters, and results where pretty good. See [the segmentation result here on the first image of drive](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/RetinaVesselsGabor.png).
- And [Gabor can be combined with learning for a good result](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0510001.pdf), or [here](http://www.icmlc.org/icmlc2011/014_icmlc2011.pdf).
- Few years ago, [they claimed to have the best algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5896442_Retinal_Blood_Vessel_Segmentation_Using_Line_Operators_and_Support_Vector_Classification), but I've never had the opportunity to test it. I was sceptic about the performance gap and the way they thresholded the line detector results, it was kind of obscure.
- But I know that nowadays, many people try to tackle the problem using CNN, but I've not heard about significant improvements.

[EDIT] To answer your specific question, you can erase the bright ring, and then apply a histogram stretching. But I think that the methods I introduced before will work better than the filter you are using.

Answer (score 0):

looks like, the solution for your problem is histogram equalization (we had the same problem for homework)

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html#gsc.tab=0